# how do I run a random statement

Tags: c

I was wondering if there is a way to run a random statement in C that I created, such as a function. I know how to run a random integer but not how to randomly pick from a list of statements that I created.

Comment: Put the statements in a `switch`, and use a random number as the controlling expression for the `switch`.

Comment: Make an array of function pointers, select a random index, and then call the function at that index.

Comment: Or an array of function pointers etc. (How do you "run an integer"?)

Comment: I am making a trivia game and want to run a random question

Comment: How about `statements[rand() % N]()` where `statements` is an array of function pointers?

Comment: To make a multiple-choice trivia game, one typically has an array of structures, where each structure has: 1) the text of the question, 2) an array with the text of the answers, 3) the index of the correct answer, 4) a flag that indicates whether the question has been asked (so questions aren't repeated). Then the code picks a random number that is used as an index into the array of structures. All the information needed to present the question and judge the answer is in the structure.

Comment: Create an array of function pointers.  Generate a random integer in the range 0 through one less than the function count.  Use that to index into the array to obtain a random function pointer.  Call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this with your `randomValue` that you got from `rand()` function:

```
int statement = randomValue % nState;
```

in above code, I assume that your program have `nSate`states and you can use this variable in your `switch`.

Comment: the value of RAND_MAX is 32,767 equal (2^15 - 1). Therefore it is difficult to overflow if you declare your variable with size is 32 bits or 64 bits.

Comment: also, if you are still worry about it, you can implement the division first with ‘double’ prefix and then round it.

Comment: Yes! I though it too complexity!!

Comment: This helps but I am not entirely sure what the nState is.